# What are the diffferences between my bash while loops?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

File:

```
cat csvfile
apple,1
orange,2
banana,3
```

Code:

```
head -2 csvfile | while read line
do
        f1=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)
        f2=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)
        echo "$f1 -> $f2"
done

while read line
do
        f1=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)
        f2=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)
        echo "$f1 -> $f2"
done <<< $(head -2 csvfile)
```

Output:

```
apple -> 1
orange -> 2
apple -> 1 orange
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think this was explained somewhere in "Related" posts; the concept you're looking for is "subshell".

Comment: `$(head -2 csvfile)` is returned as a single line, not two lines

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Because simply running these scripts would definitely show you what the differences are and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```sh
$ echo "$(head -2 csvfile)"
apple,1
orange,2

$ echo $(head -2 csvfile)
apple,1 orange,2
```

When unquoted, the command substitution results are subject to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) which transforms all sequences of whitespace (including newlines) into a single space.

There is now only 1 line to iterate over, and `echo $line | cut -d, -f2` outputs `1 orange`

Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

---

There's another potential problem that will manifest *after* the loop ends: consider

```bash
head -2 csvfile | while read line
do
        f1=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)
        f2=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)
        echo "$f1 -> $f2"
done
echo "$f1 -> $f2"
```

will output `->`

but

```sh
while read line
do
        f1=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)
        f2=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)
        echo "$f1 -> $f2"
done < <(head -2 csvfile)    # <<< a Process Substitution
echo "$f1 -> $f2"
```

will output `orange -> 2` as expected.

Bash pipelines execute each command in a separate subshell. When `while read` is the last command in a pipeline, it's variables will disappear when that subshell exits.

If you need the variables to persist, don't *pipe* input into a while loop, *redirect* the input instead.

Further reading:

- [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)
- [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: Hey thanks! this was really bugging me and the word splitting / subshell info points me in the right direction

Comment: one more quick question, what's the difference between `< <(head -2 csvfile)` and `<<< head -2 csvfile`

Comment: A process substitution is essentially a file, so `< <(head...)` is a plain redirection from a file containing the result of the `head` command. `<<<` is a [Here String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), [What does <<< mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean)